# Mean Square Error definition for symmetric models

Tags: estimation, mse

I want to estimate the parameters of the sum of two complex sinusoids embedded in Gaussian noise:

$y[n]=a_1 {\rm e}^{\,j n \theta_1} + a_2 {\rm e}^{\,j n \theta_2} + w[n]$

where $w[n]\sim {\cal N}(0,\sigma^2)$ and $n=1,\ldots,N$. Say that I want to compare the performance of different estimators (Prony, Maximum Likelihood, etc.), so I run a Monte Carlo simulation. For each realization of the noise term $w[n]$ I will obtain the estimates $\hat{a}_1$,$\hat{a}_2$,$\hat{\theta}_1$,$\hat{\theta}_2$. The problem now is that if I want to compute, say, the Mean Square Error for the amplitude estimates

$\mbox{MSE}(\hat{a}_1,\hat{a}_2)=E\left[(a_1-\hat{a}_1)^2+(a_2-\hat{a}_2)^2\right]$,

I need to associate each of the values returned by the estimator to the correct "ground truth" parameter $a_1$ or $a_2$. If the noise variance is low and $|a_i-\hat{a}_i|$ is not too small this is not hard; otherwise it does not seem to be an easy task.

Any suggestions?

Comment: ARMA may be a lead on this. Suggest looking at [Box-Jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Jenkins).